# I am facing issue while build gradle in android studio ? Please let me Know if any solution?

Tags: android, gradle, cmake, android-ndk

```
Build command failed.
Error while executing process C:\Users\RadheRadhe\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.10.2.4988404\bin\ninja.exe with arguments {-C F:\ira-app\avbsdk\sdk\.cxx\cmake\debug\arm64-v8a clean}
ninja: Entering directory `F:\ira-app\avbsdk\sdk\.cxx\cmake\debug\arm64-v8a'
[0/1] Re-running CMake...
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "F:/ira-app/avbsdk/sdk/.cxx/cmake/debug/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "F:/ira-app/avbsdk/sdk/.cxx/cmake/debug/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
FAILED: build.ninja 
C:\Users\RadheRadhe\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.10.2.4988404\bin\cmake.exe -HF:\ira-app\avbsdk\sdk -BF:\ira-app\avbsdk\sdk\.cxx\cmake\debug\arm64-v8a

CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

    cl

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

  To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
  that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
  unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
  Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
  the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

    cl

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

  To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
  that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
  unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
  Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).
```

Comment: And what does your CMakeLists.txt look like?

Comment: its normal showing version code and showing cpp libraries

Comment: Did you read the error message, or try **any** of the suggested fixes? It tells you how to fix the issue... "*Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.*"

Comment: yes i try to fix it error , i am tried to remove NDK and CMAKE in android studio and reinstall it , i am tried invalidate cache and restart android studio but the error will be showing same

Comment: It just seems odd that `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` would be set to `cl`, which is the compiler from Microsoft Visual C++. That's what I'm wondering exactly what your CMakeLists.txt contains, and possibly also the generated cmake_build_command.txt